# Admob Rewarded Video works in debug mode but not when i compile in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob, rewardedvideoad

Admob Rewarded Video works in debug mode but not when i compile in release mode.
The app force close. Why?

I also have normal and interstitial banner and both works perfectly.

In release mode the app doesn't find the methods :/

```
    The thread 'Unknown' (0xd) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
08-23 22:24:39.475 I/MonoDroid( 5129): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129): Java.Lang.LinkageError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzoc;.setRewardedVideoAdListener(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener;)V"
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <63df96eaabb24db7b7ce0b2723ec3060>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.GetMethodID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x0005b] in <1667feedb892456c8726b1f5107f4e46>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetMethodID (System.IntPtr kls, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00007] in <48c68648bb284d13bcd27ab311f23a84>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at Android.Gms.Ads.Reward.IRewardedVideoAdInvoker.set_RewardedVideoAdListener (Android.Gms.Ads.Reward.IRewardedVideoAdListener value) [0x00015] in <d86b84833e414f08b28ece392cf03659>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at MYPROJECT.Droid.JSInterfaceFunctions+<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<admob_rewardedVideoLoad>b__0 () [0x000bc] in <8b47191083144881b9f209b0044478d5>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at MYLIB.Droid.MYLIBJSInterfaceFunctions+<>c__DisplayClass110_0.<RunOnUI>b__0 () [0x00000] in <433270ae6a914e99858732bd2b05efe1>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <48c68648bb284d13bcd27ab311f23a84>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <48c68648bb284d13bcd27ab311f23a84>:0 
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:5d8aa428-a1ea-4b5c-9f22-78772d36c7cd (intptr,intptr)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.LinkageError stack trace ---
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzoc;.setRewardedVideoAdListener(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener;)V"
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-23 22:24:39.521 I/MonoDroid( 5129):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Disable the linker in the Release configuration and re-test your app, it is works, then consult : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking

Comment: It has not worked for me, the problem is that it does not find some methods in relase mode. @SushiHangover

Comment: *`problem is that it does not find some methods in release mode`*... That is either due to the Xamarin Linker removing C# IL or Proguard removing Java byte code. Disable both and re-test your release built app....

Comment: @ephramd Did you ever find a solution to this?